# Can someone explain why codes get different outputs if you don't use scopes in some cases?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm practicing coding on HackerRank, and I have the following code, which gets a different outputs.

The task is the following:
Given an array of integers, find the longest subarray where the absolute difference between any two elements is less than or equal to.

**Example:**

**a = [1,1,2,2,4,4,5,5,5];**

There are two subarrays meeting the criterion: **[1,1,2,2]** and **[4,4,5,5,5]**. The maximum length subarray has **5** elements.

The following code gets the desired output:

```
public static int pickingNumbers(List<Integer> a) {
    // Write your code here
    int max = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Collections.sort(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j< a.size(); j++){
            if(Math.abs(a.get(i)-a.get(j)) <= 1){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter > max)
            max = counter;
        counter = 0;
    

    }
    return max+1;
}
```

While this one, gets a different output -

```
public static int pickingNumbers(List<Integer> a) {
    // Write your code here
    int max = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Collections.sort(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j< a.size(); j++){
            if(Math.abs(a.get(i)-a.get(j)) <= 1){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter > max){
            max = counter;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return max+1;
}
```

As you can see, the difference between the 2 codes are just the brackets after the  `if(counter > max)` part. In the latter case, the counter is always **1** unit more than it should be.
Can anyone please explain it to me, why the code behaves different in this case?

Comment: Irrespective of what you're actually asking, `counter` should be declared inside the i for loop, and initialized to zero there.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the first snippet `counter = 0;` is **not** in the `if` block.

When `if` is not enclosed in brackets, it only evaluates the *first* instruction after it, so the `counter = 0;` is always executed.

Here's an example with better indentation:

```java
public static int pickingNumbers(List<Integer> a)
{
    int max = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Collections.sort(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j< a.size(); j++)
        {
            if(Math.abs(a.get(i)-a.get(j)) <= 1)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter > max)
            max = counter;
        
        counter = 0; // Not in the if statement, so the counter is always reset!
    }
    return max+1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the lame question. I didn't know this.

Comment: @Mate25 No worries!

Answer (score 0):

```
const genObj = (ar) => {
  let obj = {}
  for(let i of ar) {
    !(obj[i])? obj[i] = 1 : obj[i]++ 
  }
  return obj
}

function pickingNumbers(a) {
    // Write your code here
   let obj = genObj(a)
    let k = Object.keys(genObj(a))
    let i = 0
    let max = 0
    while (i <= k.length - 1) {
        for(let j = i; j <= k.length - 1; j++){
            if(i === j) continue
            if(Math.abs(k[i] - k[j]) <= 1) {
                if(obj[k[i]] + obj[k[j]] > max) 
                    max = obj[k[i]] + obj[k[j]]
            }
        }
        i++
    }

    return max > Math.max(...Object.values(obj)) ? max : Math.max(...Object.values(obj))
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything to OP